# how to fix You_Should_Not_Call_base_In_This_Method

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using vision kit and I have issue with calling the delegate did finish

The method is implemented like this

```
   public override void Finish(ViewController controller, CameraScan scan)
        {
           base.DidFinish(controller, scan);
        }
```

However I get an exception that

```
Foundation.You_Should_Not_Call_base_In_This_Method: Exception of type 'Foundation.You_Should_Not_Call_base_In_This_Method' was thrown.
```

I have found out that iOS shows this method when they don't have the base class, but how else can I access it?

Answer (score 0):

ok, so I found an swer here, it seems that just remove the call to base class will do https://www.programmersought.com/article/86644372205/